How to Avoid Circular Connections in Android VPN
I have a proxy core written in Golang, which I have compiled as an AAR (Android Archive) to use in my Android Kotlin app. When I start the VPN using vpnservice.Builder, I route all traffic to my proxy app builder.route("0.0.0.0", 0). However, I am encountering a problem with circular connections.
Here's what happens:
   1-The proxy client tries to connect to the proxy server.
   2-The request loops back to the client because all traffic is routed to my proxy client app.

I found the protect() method in the Android documentation, which can protect a socket and route connections through the network stack instead of the VPN interface. While this method is useful, my app creates a new socket in the Golang code for each new connection on the device. As a result, I cannot protect a large number of sockets per second in Android.
How can I handle this problem to avoid circular connections in my proxy app?
Any suggestions or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.
